# SQL Server stored procedure cache

Tags: sql-server, stored-procedures, user-defined-functions, openquery

I am trying to execute the same selection by two various methods.

First via a **table-valued function** using stored procedure

```
SELECT * FROM dbo.DF_PRODUCTS();
```

Second via `openquery`, by  executing stored procedure

```
SELECT * 
FROM openquery([servername], 
               'SET FMTONLY OFF exec DatabaseName.dbo.My_StoredProcedure')
```

The problem is that I get various results and I think the problem is in stored procedure cache. Can anyone help me with this?

Comment: Can your post your stored proc code?

Comment: If your  concern is sp cache then u go ahead n delete it using DBCC FREEPROCCACHE or since sql server cache are transient close ur ssms n then reopen it .Else as suggested by @Limey post ur SP code

Answer (score 0):

If you're getting different results from running the exact same code, and the 'only' (perceived) difference is that you are running one through an OPENQUERY command, do a sanity check and confirm that the OPENQUERY([servername]...) is definitely running against the same server as your first query.

The likeliest scenario is that your linked server is different to the one you're running against locally - e.g. you're running against a local database versus a development/test/staging/live database.